# How to customize macOS Installer's name for my package made with productbuild?

Tags: xcode, macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I have a build target set up in my Xcode project to create a package from a number of other targets. I added a build phase script that simply runs `productbuild`, which can automatically detect just about everything needed for my install:

```
productbuild \
--root "$INSTALL_ROOT" \
--identifier "$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" \
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.pkg"
```

This package works great functionally, but when I open it, the Installer.app is missing a name for it:

[image: Screenshot of Install.app startup screen]

The window title should say "Install {Useful App}" and the little label below that should say "Welcome to the {Useful App} Installer".

How do I give my installer package a name/title for the UI? Can I do it while still using the `--root` option, or do I need to synthesize and then forever manually maintain a distribution file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `title` as described in the [Distribution Definition XML Schema Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW10).